# How do I use Java getResource() to get a resource from a parent directory?

Tags: java, path

I've tried numerous methods now, including FilenameUtils.normalize() from commons IO, but I can't seem to be able to get a resource in another folder to get a Java FXML file.

The code is the following

```
  try {
     root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../plugin/PluginSelection.fxml"));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(QueueOperationsController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
```

Where the desired FXML file is:

```
gui
   dialogues
      plugins
         PluginSelection.fxml // desired file
      dataset
         QueueOperationsController // current class
```

How do I best get the desired file's URL?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the `plugin` folder located?

Comment: Your file tree shows a directory called *plugin*, but your code sample refers to a directory called *plugins*. Could that be the problem?

Comment: (getClass().getResource("../plugin/PluginSelection.fxml")); works for me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get resources relative to the `Class` or the context root. In your example putting `/` at the start of the string if thats your package structure in your application. Try

```
getClass().getResource("/gui/dialogues/plugins/PluginSelection.fxml")
```

Comment: changed it to:         root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/pdpro/gui/dialogues/plugin/PluginSelection.fxml"));    and it works like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: If my resource was four directories higher than the class (`../../../../resource`), would I just type `////resource`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that if we use .getResource only when searching in marked as resource folder. Otherwise, even if folder path is correct, but it's not marked as resource folder we'll got an error.
So, I do this way:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/java/CRUD/bnkseekCRUD.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load(fileInputStream);
```