# Spark load csv file in jar from resources folder

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a Spark application running on Scala that reads a `.csv` file that is located in `src/main/resources` directory and saves it on the local `hdfs` instance. Everything works charming when I run it locally, whenever I bundle it as a .jar file however and deploy it on a server something goes wrong...

This is my code that that is located in `src/main/scala`, the location of my datafile is `src/main/resources/dataset.csv`:

```
val df = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load(getClass.getResource("dataset.csv").toString())
```

When I make a jar by calling `sbt package` and deploy this to my server however, I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
java.net.URISyntaxException: 
Relative path in absolute URI: jar:file:/root/./myapp_2.11-0.1.jar!/dataset.csv
```

How can I correctly link to my file?

Comment: Can you just store the csv file in HDFS and read it from your Spark job and then write it back out? This seems like a better design, to separate the data from the app that processes it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Java getResource() to get a resource from a parent directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389731/how-do-i-use-java-getresource-to-get-a-resource-from-a-parent-directory)

Answer (score 5):

Use `getPath()` on the `URL` object returned from `getResource` to get an absolute path:

```scala
getClass.getResource("data.csv").getPath()
```

Like so:

`/upload-data-scala-project/target/scala-2.11/classes/data.csv`

Using `toString` will give you a string representation of the URL like:

`file:/upload-data-scala-project/target/scala-2.11/classes/data.csv`

which has no leading slash, and is thus interpreted as an relative path.

Comment: I receive "21/02/24 10:53:27 ERROR yarn.Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException" when executed in Yarn.

Comment: @AndreVieiradeLima I'm not sure why the above isn't working, but I got that same error you did. I changed it to `getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(filename).getPath` and it came through.

Comment: @davidshere I solved the error by adding a leading slash: `getClass.getResource(s"/$filename").getPath`

Answer (score 0):

When you have a path in your resources and deploy the code in cluster, the resources folder will be somewhere based on configuration path you provided in your code deploy set up
Accordingly, you can specify that file by referring to the complete path of the resources folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

From the error message, it looks like spark is expecting an absolute path and you are giving a relative path to the file. I always provide an absolute path to the file (hdfs:// if the file is in HDFS or file:// if the file is local). Sample code below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("My spark app").config("master","yarn").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.read.json("hdfs:///user/amalprakash32203955/data/people.json")
```